# How to resolve problem with push an values and their replacement after that?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

how to resolve some issue in this code with selected goods if exists. For example, the user inserts selected goods or services with them quantity, deviceId, etc and everything is ok. But when user wants to add some selected good in next row with another deviceID it only replaces existed selected good and add more quantity in them, but previous deviceID stay ahead. How to resolve this? Thanks a lot.

```
addItem() {

    if (this.ListOfUsedMaterials.length) {

      let exists: boolean = false;
      this.ListOfUsedMaterials.forEach(item => {
        if (item.goodId == this.selectedGood.id) {
          exists = true;
          item.quantity += Number(this.item.quantity);
          this.item.quantity = "";
          this.selectedGood = "";

        }
      });

      if (!exists) {

        this.ListOfUsedMaterials.push({
          title: this.selectedGood.value,
          quantity: Number(this.item.quantity),
          goodId: this.selectedGood.id,
          unit: this.selectedGood.unit,
          device: this.deviceTypId,
          manufacturer: this.deviceManufacturerId,
          mark: this.deviceMark
        });

        this.onClear(event);
        console.log('Ovo :', this.ListOfUsedMaterials);
        //this.item.quantity = "";
        //this.selectedGood = "";
      }

    } else {
      this.ListOfUsedMaterials.push({
        title: this.selectedGood.value,
        quantity: Number(this.item.quantity),
        goodId: this.selectedGood.id,
        unit: this.selectedGood.unit,
        device: this.deviceTypId,
        manufacturer: this.deviceManufacturerId,
        mark: this.deviceMark

      });
      console.log('Ovo :', this.ListOfUsedMaterials);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to match items by both keys (`goodId` and `device`). Here is a cleaner version of your code:

```
addItem() {
    const found = this.ListOfUsedMaterials.find(item => 
        item.goodId == this.selectedGood.id && item.device == this.deviceTypId);
    if (found) {
        found.quantity += Number(this.item.quantity);
        this.item.quantity = "";
        this.selectedGood = "";
    } else {
        this.ListOfUsedMaterials.push({
            title: this.selectedGood.value,
            quantity: Number(this.item.quantity),
            goodId: this.selectedGood.id,
            unit: this.selectedGood.unit,
            device: this.deviceTypId,
            manufacturer: this.deviceManufacturerId,
            mark: this.deviceMark
        });
        this.onClear(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tatar: it's ok but i've got an error cannot read a property value of undefined.

Comment: @Zeljk0 what property?

Comment: deviceTypeID, when i choose an element i've got that error.

Comment: Tatar: i've got an issues when  user want to delete item per item 

deleteItemfromArray(itemToDelete) {
    this.ListOfUsedMaterials = this.ListOfUsedMaterials
      .filter(item => item.goodId != itemToDelete.goodId);
  }

Comment: @Zeljk0 as you see in my code it's called `deviceTypId` I copied it from your code but it's probably a typo and needs to be updated with what your variable is actually named!

Comment: man, i also have below in my code delete item from array: HEre's a code: deleteItemfromArray(itemToDelete) {
    this.ListOfUsedMaterials = this.ListOfUsedMaterials
      .filter(item => item.goodId != itemToDelete.goodId);
  }
when i add two same selected goods and when user want to delete one of them, code delete both..... :(